# Using a Custom UIView for iCarousel

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, icarousel

I am trying to use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) to display a series of items. I wanted to reuse a storyboard UIView for this, so I created a custom class of a UIView. I also created an XIB file for this, and I set up the view to my preference. I then hooked up the outlets of my view to the class. I am now trying to recreate a UIView so I can use it for my carousel. Here is my custom class of UIView:

[image: Custom Class]

Here is my code for my Carousel:

```
func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    return costs.count
}

func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let rView = ReturnView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 220))
    rView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    print(rView.deleteBtn)//fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value
    return rView

}
```

As you can see from my fatal error, delete button does not exist. This is the same with the rest of my elements. None of the subviews appear:

[image: Subviews]

How can I get the subviews to appear on my iCarousel? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your carousel function

```
{
var myView : UIView
if(myView != nil)
{
 myView = view as! ReturnView    
}
else{
var topLevelObjects : NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("your_xib_name", owner: self, options: nil)
myView = topLevelObjects.objectAtIndex(0) as!  ReturnView
}
return myView }
```

You need to load the view from ur xib on top of current view. Make sure u have marked the owner of Custom view u have created as PRESENT view controller where you are adding carousel

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
rView.addSubview(myButtonName)
```

and for the 'fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value' try this:

```
if deleteBtn != nil{
print(rView.deleteBtn)
}
```

I truly don't understand what you are trying to do, "printing a button?" but this might be an appropriate way of doing this. Hope this helps... :)))